# Vscode autocompletion for not imported module

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to have autocompletion for `chai` assert. When I import it directly in each test file by `import { assert } from 'chai'`, it works of course. But I find importing assert in every test file a little inconvenient, that's way I import `chai/register-assert` once to have `assert` available globally. But then, autocompletion doesn't work. Is it possible to tell vscode to autocomplete a library which is not explicitly imported in a give module?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: No, but actually I think it is just better to `import { assert } from 'chai'` anyway, to be explicit - one point of modular apps, so why not to use it in tests as well.