# Visual Studio Code intellisense for globally registered modules in a bootstrapping script

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, node-modules

I am trying to get **Visual Studio** Code `intellisense` to work for the modules that I require in `bootstrap.js`, which is relative to the `src` folder.

This is the folder structure:

```
├───src
│   ├───components
│   │   ├───partials
│   │   │   ├───step1
│   │   │   ├───step2
│   │   │   └───step3
│   │   ├───views
│   │   └───windows
│   └───router
├───static
└───style
```

This is what `bootstrap.js` looks like:

```
'use strict';

try {
    global._ = require('lodash');
    global.axios = require('axios');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error loading libraries in "boostrap.js": ${e}`);
}
```

`bootstrap.js` is required in `main.js` (i.e., also relative to `src/`) which looks like this:

```
// Load project global dependencies.
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
});
```

Then, within `components/partials/step1/Example.vue`, I try to get `intellisense` by typing `_.<CTRL + SPACE>` (i.e., to load `lodash`). Currently, when I do this, I only get suggestions for other variables that I declared in that file alone.

I tried adding a `jsconfig.json` relative to `src/` with all sorts of settings, but it din't work, e.g.:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },

    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ]
}
```

I found something related here, but unanswered: [Vscode autocompletion for not imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46360262/5252007)

How can I get `intellisense` to work in this case?

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: were you able to find a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is by added an import statement into the script tag on the individual vue file (in your case i.e. Example.vue)
So, it may look like this:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        methods: {
            myMethod() {
                axios.[post...]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```